# Create dataframe from nested dictionary keeping nested dictionary as column

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

I have the following nested dictionary and I would like to convert it to a dataframe.

[image: Nested Dictionary]

The first two columns will be the keys of the first dictionary and the third column will be the nested dictionary.

[image: The first two columns of the dataframe]

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please dont post code as images. post the code.  What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your editing.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you would provided a sample data set of your `sample_inv` DF (5-7 rows in __text__ format), explained what do you want to do and provided a desired result set. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the greatest input data, but if you're confident that the structure of the dictionary won't change, you could try something like the below:

```
DataFrame([
        [x[0] for x in nested_dict.keys()],
        [x[1] for x in nested_dict.keys()],
        [x for x in nested_dict.values()],
    ]).T
```

This should give you a DataFrame to your specs.

```
    0           1   2
0   timestamp4  324 {326: 3}
1   timestamp3  323 {325: 2}
2   timestamp   321 {321: 0}
3   timestamp2  322 {323: 1}
```